# create BITMAP image from hex String Java

Tags: java, bitmap, javax.imageio

I have a requirement to create a BMP image (black & white) from the hex string created through Excel Macro. I have next to zero experience working on this and need some help. Below is the Hex String, output image example of the hex, and little code snippet that I am trying :

**String**:

`001E00FE07FE3FE03C003C003F801FFE03FE007E3E003FE03FFC0FFE0E3E0FFE3FFC3FE03E0000000FF83FFC3FFE300630063006380E180C00003E003FE03FFC0FFE0E3E0FFE3FFC3FE03E00000000003FFE3FFE3FFE01F807F01FC03FFE3FFE3FFE0000000E000E000E3FFE3FFE3FFE000E000E000E0000`

**Image to be created of the above string:**

[image]

**Code Snippet :**

```
public void createImageFromHex() throws IOException {
        String hex="001E00FE07FE3FE03C003C003F801FFE03FE007E3E003FE03FFC0FFE0E3E0FFE3FFC3FE03E0000000FF83FFC3FFE300630063006380E180C00003E003FE03FFC0FFE0E3E0FFE3FFC3FE03E00000000003FFE3FFE3FFE01F807F01FC03FFE3FFE3FFE0000000E000E000E3FFE3FFE3FFE000E000E000E0000";

        byte[] imageInByte= ByteString.decodeHex(hex).toByteArray();

        for (byte b : imageInByte) {
            System.out.println("Byte : " + b);

        }
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);

        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.BITMASK);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics(font);
        g2d.dispose();

        int width = fm.stringWidth(hex);
        int height = fm.getHeight();

        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.BITMASK);
        g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.drawString(hex, 0, fm.getAscent());
        g2d.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", new File("Hex.bmp"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the result you got from this attempt?

Comment: The string itself saved as image file. Entire string. @n247s

Comment: You don't need to use a font. You need to convert each pair of bytes to a number and set the correct bits in your image to black, based on the '1's in the number. The MSB is at the bottom of the image, the LSB at the top. Each pair of bytes is a single column from left to right.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for the comment, however, I have literally zero experience with image manipulation / creating etc. Is it possible for you to point me to right direction (blog / docs) anything from where I can get started ?

Comment: I don’t know what ByteString is, but [java.util.HexFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) will do the same thing without requiring an external dependency:  `byte[] imageInByte = HexFormat.of().parseHex(hex);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue here is *the format of the hex/binary data*. You need to know this from some kind of specification, from the device/software/service that produces the hex string. From the data and sample image, I believe @tgdavies has correctly reverse-engineered it.

Each pixel is one bit. The white pixels are stored as 0, black as 1. Each *column* of pixels is stored as two bytes. Each column is stored bottom-up.

Assuming that format is correct, it's quite trivial to write code to convert it:

```java
public void createImageFromHex() throws IOException {
    // Assumption: hex contains a bitmap format, where
    //   * each pair of bytes is one *column*
    //   * each column is stored "bottom-up" (LSB is bottom pixel, MSB is top pixel)
    String hex = "001E00FE07FE3FE03C003C003F801FFE03FE007E3E003FE03FFC0FFE0E3E0FFE3FFC3FE03E0000000FF83FFC3FFE300630063006380E180C00003E003FE03FFC0FFE0E3E0FFE3FFC3FE03E00000000003FFE3FFE3FFE01F807F01FC03FFE3FFE3FFE0000000E000E000E3FFE3FFE3FFE000E000E000E0000";

    // (result is 120 bytes)
    byte[] imageInByte = ByteString.decodeHex(hex).toByteArray();

    int height = 16; // 16 according to sample
    int width = imageInByte.length / 2; // 60 according to the sample, but as we know each column is 16 bits or 2 bytes, we can calculate it

    // Create a BufferedImage of correct type: For a bitmap this is TYPE_BYTE_BINARY
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

    // Loop over pixels and insert black or white
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int pos = height * x + y;
            int bytePos = pos / 8;
            int bitPos = 7 - (pos % 8);
            byte value = imageInByte[bytePos];

            int bit = (value >> bitPos) & 1;

            // Each pixel is either all white (0) or all black (1)
            int rgb = bit != 0 ? 0x000000 : 0xFFFFFF;
            img.setRGB(x, height - 1 - y, rgb);
        }
    }

    // Write to BMP format
    File output = new File("Hex.bmp");
    if (!ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", output)) {
        System.err.printf("Could not write %s in BMP format...%n", output.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Result file:

[image: Hex.bmp]

Comment: Thank you is a very small word for this !